# Optimizing recursion in python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, methods

I'm having trouble on optimizing recursion on python. So I want to generate every possibilities in array/list consist of 10 elements, which is can be filled with 0-9 number on each elements.
So, I decided to use recursion on this case, here is:

```
routes = []
route = []

def generateRoutes(route, floor):
    if floor >= 10:
        routes.append(route)
    else:
        for channel in range(0, 10):
            new_route=route.copy()
            new_route.append(channel)
            generateRoutes(new_route, floor + 1)

generateRoutes(route, 0)
```

My code takes eternity to finish the task (not to mention takes a lot of memory). My question is, Is there a way to solve/optimize my code?
(I also open for other method than recursion)

Edit:
Added detail on how the function called

Comment: So, do you essentially want to generate numbers between 0 and 9,999,999,999? Assuming that you can generate 1,000,000 numbers per second, that's still more than 2,5 hours.

Comment: There are 10e10 possible lists then, which means it would take at least 100 GiB to store the elements (and likely way more, especially since Python objects are not very "cheap").

Comment: You didn't include all your code. What is ```routes```, how are you calling ```generateRoutes()``` in the first place?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So, pretty much impossible to generate all of them?

Comment: @TomLubenow Edited

Comment: Maybe not impossible (provided you have enough memory) but probably pointless. What would you do with such a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already a non-recursive, lazy solution available via the `itertools` module:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> routes = itertools.product(range(10), repeat=10)
```

Each value is generated on demand as you iterate over `routes`, rather than storing all 10 billion of them in memory at once.

```
>>> print(list(itertools.islice(routes, 20)))
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9)]
>>> print(list(itertools.islice(routes, 20)))
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 6), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 9), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) is exactly what you want.
Most likely something like this:

```py
import itertools
nums = list(range(0, 10))
routes = list(itertools.product(nums, LENGTH))
```

To fix your memory problem you should consider using it as a generator:

```py
import itertools
nums = list(range(0, 10))
for route in itertools.product(nums, LENGTH):
    # YOUR_STUFF
```

And if you really just want to iterate through the number why not do

```py
for i in range(10**LENGTH):
    ...
```

Well, to find a better solution I think we need a little more information about what you want to achieve as I feel like this approach will not the best one for what you want to do.